# Multiple RewriteConditions in Apache .htaccess configuration issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite URLs that don't exist to use my index.php file while also appending the HTTP:Authorization environment variable to my script. So far I've only been able to get one or the other working at a time. Not both. Can someone tell me where is the error in my .htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine on

# Get HTTP authorization
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^Basic.*

# Append to URL
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?_auth=%{HTTP:Authorization} [QSA,L]

# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?_auth=%{HTTP:Authorization} [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing this, surely the authorisation header must be accessible in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your .htaccess works fine in my test environment. I get the `_auth` argument with every request.

But you don't need all these `RewriteCond`s, just one `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?_auth=%{HTTP:Authorization} [QSA,L]
```

This will rewrite all requests to `index.php`, adding the authorization header as an `_auth` argument.

If you want only non-existing URLs to be rewritten with an `_auth` argument, just prepend the `RewriteCond`s to the `RewriteRule`. If caching is an issue in your case, add the `RewriteCond HTTP:Authorization` as well

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^Basic
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?_auth=%{HTTP:Authorization} [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Obviously she needs the conditions otherwise all resources like images and scripts are rewritten to index.php

Comment: @kjetilh They will be rewritten with the original .htaccess as well, unless other recources are separate with a separate .htaccess.

Comment: well yes, seems to me she needs to move the first condition that looks for *^Basic* in the Authorization header to the bottom rule and scrap the first rule

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the Authorization header is accessible via PHP so it seems unnecessary to append the value as a query argument.

See the [$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) superglobal, perhaps the key **AUTH_TYPE** is what you're looking for?

```
<?php $_SERVER['AUTH_TYPE']) ?>
```

Anyway if you still persist on the .htaccess solution then really you could just scrap the entire first rule all together; the _auth parameter will be appended with the Authorization header if it exists.

```
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?_auth=%{HTTP:Authorization} [QSA,L]
```